# How to play blob mysql audio data in Html5 Audiio tag...?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I've finished to store audio blob(binary) data in to MySQL DB. But how can i show that blob data in my HTML page for a audio tag.

Answer (score 1):

just create a PHP script that will fetch the audio data from DB and write it as a result and (the most important) **change the result page content-type**. Here is an example of such basic script:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "testDB");

$query = "SELECT * FROM testTable";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    header("Content-type: audio/mpeg"); 
    echo $row['audioData'];

    $result->free();
}

$mysqli->close();
?>
```

The most important line is:

```
header("Content-type: audio/mpeg");
```

which tells the browser to interpret the content as binary audio data. This is an example for mp3 files. If you use other encoding you have to change **audio/mpeg** to proper value of your file (you can find proper values easily in the Internet).

And simple HTML page to use this script (look carefully on the **src** value of audio source tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<audio controls>
  <source src="yourScript.php" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope it helps :)